# sql position of subquery's name

Tags: sql, subquery, sybase

I don't know where is the right position of subquery

my query is

```
SELECT *
FROM (
            SELECT *
            FROM ESMBLNK
            UNION ALL
            SELECT *
            FROM ESMVDGL
            WHERE condition1
              AND condition2
        )
```

I have to put the name of subquery but don't know how to insert it

Comment: After the ending `)`.

Comment: SELECT *
FROM (
            SELECT *
            FROM ESMBLNK
            UNION ALL
            SELECT *
            FROM ESMVDGL
            WHERE condition1
              AND condition2
        ) as name

Comment: * from both tables... same columns?

Comment: and this is not a subquery, this is a derived table structure

Answer (score 1):

As Jarlh said, the name must go after the end of the FROM ( ), for example, I call the subquery A. By the way, your WHERE clause will only affect ESMVDGL.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM ESMBLNK
        UNION ALL
        SELECT *
        FROM ESMVDGL
        WHERE condition1
          AND condition2
    ) A
```

Comment: typo: WHERE clause will only affect ESMVDGL